# from-end does not work as I expect in position

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
[18]> (position 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) :from-end nil)
2
[19]> (position 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) :from-end t)
2
```

What to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`position` is working as documented. The [hyperspec says](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm):

> The position returned is the index within sequence of the leftmost (if from-end is true) or of the rightmost (if from-end is false) element that satisfies the test; otherwise nil is returned. The index returned is relative to the left-hand end of the entire sequence, *regardless of the value of start, end, or from-end*.

Comment: Ah. So I have to take length and subtract. Thanks.

Comment: "of the leftmost (if from-end is true) or of the rightmost (if from-end is false)" Huh? Isn't that exactly the wrong way around?

Comment: @sepp2k thats what i thought, but that is directly from the hyperspec! I havn't got CL on this comp to test, but that is the opposite to the behaviour i remember

Comment: @tobyo: `(position 1 '(1 2 3 1) :from-end t)` returns 3 here (SBCL 1.0.40.0), so I'm guessing it's a mistake in the hyperspec.

Comment: Looks like it.  CLTL2 says: "If a non-nil :from-end keyword argument is specified, then the result is the index of the rightmost element satisfying the test. (The index returned, however, is an index from the left-hand end, as usual.)"

Answer (score 2):

Try `(position 3 '(1 2 3 4 3 2 1) :from-end t)` to see what the `:from-end` keyword actually does...

what you appear to want is much simpler - `(- (length list) (position elem list))`